# Dúvida em python com Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Olá, preciso exibir uma área determinada da imagem com as bordas, utilizando o canny, e exibi-la em cima da própria imagem, como no exemplo abaixo.

[image: Exemplo]

O meu código exibe a área selecioanda e essa área com o filtro Canny, porem em janelas diferentes.

[image: Meu resultado]

O que preciso fazer para ter essa exibição como no exemplo? Pensei em utilizar a função Rect mas não consegui.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_src = cv2.imread('moon.jpg')

roi = cv2.selectROI(img_src)
roi_cropped = img_src[int (roi [1]): int (roi [1] + roi [3]), int (roi [0]): int (roi [0] + roi [2])]
cv2.imshow('ROI', roi_cropped)

canny = cv2.Canny(roi_cropped, 100, 200)
cv2.imshow('Image canny', canny)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O motivo de você não ter conseguido deve-se ao fato da imagem original (`img_src`) ser um numpy array onde cada elemento possui três valores, porém a imagem canny (`canny`) é um numpy array onde cada elemento possui o valor 0 ou 255.

Sendo assim, para colocar o `canny` em cima do `img_src`, você tem que transformar de 0 para [0, 0, 0] e de 255 para [255, 255, 255].

Farei isso aqui da forma mais simples possível, mas acredito que existam outras formas mais rápidas.

### Carregando libraries

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

### Lendo imagem original e croping

```
img_src = cv2.imread('foto.jpeg')

roi = cv2.selectROI(img_src)
roi_cropped = img_src[int (roi [1]): int (roi [1] + roi [3]), int (roi [0]): int (roi [0] + roi [2])]

cv2.imshow('ROI', roi_cropped)
```

### Gerando canny

```
canny = cv2.Canny(roi_cropped, 100, 200)
cv2.imshow('Image canny', canny)
```

### A "mágica" acontece aqui

```
rows, cols = canny.shape

l = []

for row in range(rows):
    l.append([])
    for col in range(cols):
        item = [0, 0, 0]
        if canny[row, col] == 255:
           item = [255, 255, 255]
        l[-1].append(item)
```

**Nota 1** `canny` é algo como [[0, 0, 255, 0...], [0, 255, 255, 0...]...]

**Nota 2** `l` é algo como [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]...], [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]...]...]

### Atribuindo `l` à imagem original

```
img_src[int (roi [1]): int (roi [1] + roi [3]), int (roi [0]): int (roi [0] + roi [2])] = np.array(l)

cv2.imshow('Imagem alterada', img_src)
```

Neste exemplo teríamos:

[image: Original]
[image: ROI]
[image: canny]
[image: Original alterada]

Comment: Muito obrigada, Paulo! A explicação ajudou muito, tudo ficou mais claro agora. E realmente, a transformação do 0 e do 255 foi algo que não me atentei.

Answer (score -1):

eu fiz uma função que faz isso de forma eficiente:

```
def merge_image(back, front, x,y):
    # convert to rgba
    if back.shape[2] == 3:
        back = cv2.cvtColor(back, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    if front.shape[2] == 3:
        front = cv2.cvtColor(front, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

    # crop the overlay from both images
    bh,bw = back.shape[:2]
    fh,fw = front.shape[:2]
    x1, x2 = max(x, 0), min(x+fw, bw)
    y1, y2 = max(y, 0), min(y+fh, bh)
    front_cropped = front[y1-y:y2-y, x1-x:x2-x]
    back_cropped = back[y1:y2, x1:x2]

    alpha_front = front_cropped[:,:,3:4] / 255
    alpha_back = back_cropped[:,:,3:4] / 255
    
    # replace an area in result with overlay
    result = back.copy()
    print(f'af: {alpha_front.shape}\nab: {alpha_back.shape}\nfront_cropped: {front_cropped.shape}\nback_cropped: {back_cropped.shape}')
    result[y1:y2, x1:x2, :3] = alpha_front * front_cropped[:,:,:3] + (1-alpha_front) * back_cropped[:,:,:3]
    result[y1:y2, x1:x2, 3:4] = (alpha_front + alpha_back) / (1 + alpha_front*alpha_back) * 255

    return result
```

no input dela vc usa a imagem de fundo depois a imagem que vem do canny e a posição inicial dela do x e y 1 da onde ela vai estar.
O resultado desta função ja vai ser a imagem da forma q vc precisa.

Comment: Obrigada, Jasar!